# MAUI App cannot reading certificates on MacOS

Tags: macos, maui

I created a MAUI App with visual studio 2022 (version 17.6.10) on Mac OS version 13.6.3. The scope is read the certificates stored on the machine, but I have no result.

The code used on the MAUI app is this:

```
foreach (StoreLocation storeLocation in (StoreLocation\[\])
Enum.GetValues(typeof(StoreLocation)))
{
foreach (StoreName storeName in (StoreName\[\])
Enum.GetValues(typeof(StoreName)))
{
X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);

                    try
                    {
                 
       store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    
                        Console.WriteLine("Yes    {0,4}  {1}, {2}",
                            store.Certificates.Count, store.Name, store.Location);
    
                        s += $"Yes    {store.Certificates.Count}  {store.Name}, {store.Location}"+Environment.NewLine;
    
                        foreach (var c in store.Certificates)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"name {c.Subject}");
                            s += $"name {c.Subject}"+Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (CryptographicException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No           {0}, {1}",
                            store.Name, store.Location);
                        s += $"No {store.Name} {store.Location}"+Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
             }
```

The output is this:

```
No AddressBook CurrentUser
No AuthRoot CurrentUser
No CA CurrentUser
Yes 0 Disallowed, CurrentUser
Yes 0 My, CurrentUser
No Root CurrentUser
No TrustedPeople CurrentUser
No TrustedPublisher CurrentUser
No AddressBook LocalMachine
No AuthRoot LocalMachine
No CA LocalMachine
No Disallowed LocalMachine
No My LocalMachine
No Root LocalMachine
No TrustedPeople LocalMachine
No TrustedPublisher LocalMachine
```

The same code used on a console application runs correctly with this output:

```
No AddressBook, CurrentUser
No AuthRoot, CurrentUser
No CA, CurrentUser
Yes 0 Disallowed, CurrentUser
Yes 50 My, CurrentUser
Yes 0 Root, CurrentUser
No TrustedPeople, CurrentUser
No TrustedPublisher, CurrentUser
No AddressBook, LocalMachine
No AuthRoot, LocalMachine
No CA, LocalMachine
Yes 0 Disallowed, LocalMachine
Yes 4 My, LocalMachine
Yes 158 Root, LocalMachine
No TrustedPeople, LocalMachine
No TrustedPublisher, LocalMachine
```

Why the MAUI app doesn't show the certificates correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use root privileges for the console application?

Comment: No, both run from visual studio without any root privileges

Comment: I have to point out that the certificate I have to read has been added by a smartcard and I also noticed that with the console application I cannot read the private key. With the same code on windows it's ok. There are some limitations in this regard ? thanks